# How can I remove all columns before a specific column in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to remove all columns **before** a specified column.

Sample data:
In `mpg`, these are the following column names in order:

```
names(mpg)

[1] "manufacturer", "model", "displ", "year", "cyl", "trans", "drv", "cty", 

[9] "hwy", "fl", "class"
```

Say I want to delete all columns before the column "`cyl`", I would do:

```
mpg[-(1:4)]
```

But in my **actual data**, sometimes the number of columns before the specified column (i.e. `cyl`) changes. So instead of 4 columns (`manufacturer, model, displ, year`) always being before the desired column (`cyl`), sometimes there's 3 or 7, etc.

How do I adjust this code so that I ensure that all columns including and after "`cyl`" are included?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `which` to get the right index and subset using that. You need to subtract 1 because you don't want to drop the `cyl` column.

If you are already using `tidyverse` tools (which seems likely since you are using an example dataset from `ggplot2`), you can also do this with `dplyr::select()` and `tidyselect::last_col()` as below. The syntax is that you can refer to column selections by `colnamea:colnameb`, which would be all columns from `colnamea` to `colnameb` inclusive. `last_col` is a reference to the last column in the data frame since we don't automatically know what that is here.

```r
remove_up_to <- function(df, colname){
  col_i <- which(colnames(df) == colname) - 1
  df[-(1:col_i)]
}

library(tidyverse)
remove_up_to(mpg, "cyl")
#> # A tibble: 234 x 7
#>      cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
#>    <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
#>  2     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
#>  3     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
#>  4     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
#>  5     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
#>  6     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
#>  7     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
#>  8     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
#>  9     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
#> 10     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
#> # ... with 224 more rows
mpg %>% select(cyl:tidyselect::last_col())
#> # A tibble: 234 x 7
#>      cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
#>    <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
#>  2     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
#>  3     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
#>  4     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
#>  5     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
#>  6     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
#>  7     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
#>  8     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
#>  9     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
#> 10     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
#> # ... with 224 more rows
```

Created on 2018-08-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

The other methods are likely faster and clearer. Here's an obscure method:

```
mpg[ !cumall(!("cyl" == colnames(mpg))) ]
```